# i got error in this code expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant|

Tags: c

I want to know why did i get this error?
"D:\C Programming\C training projects\bubblePointer\main.c|6|error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant".
I need to understand why< however the code in "C how to program" pass  size of array also

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size 10

//prototype
void bubble(unsigned int a[],const size_t size);
void swap(unsigned int *ptr1,unsigned int *ptr2);

int main()
{

unsigned int response[size] =
{6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9};
 bubble(response,size);

    return 0;
}
void bubble(unsigned int a[],const size_t  size)
{
    int pass;
    for(pass=0;pass<size-1;pass++)
    {
        int j;
        for(j=0;j<size-1;j++)
        {
    // swap adjacent elements if they’re out of order
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
            {
            swap(&a[j],&a[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }
    // output sorted array
 size_t i;
 for ( i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
 printf("%4d", a[i]);
  }

}

void swap(unsigned int *ptr1,unsigned int *ptr2)
{

        unsigned int hold;
        hold=*ptr1;
        *ptr1=*ptr2;
        *ptr2=hold;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `#define size 10` instructs the pre-processor to replace *all* instances of the token `size` with `10`. Thus, your declaration (and definition) of the function:

```c
void bubble(unsigned int a[],const size_t size);
```

will be converted to:

```c
void bubble(unsigned int a[],const size_t 10);
```

before the *actual* compilation process gets to work.

Can you see what's wrong with that second definition? Of course, you can't use `10` as the name of a parameter.

What you need to do is: **either** rename that parameter (say, `size_arg`) **or** (depending on your reason for defining the `size` macro in the first place) remove that parameter from the function and just use that predefinition in the function's code.